# Slow query with derived table in FROM clause

Tags: sql, mariadb, derived-table

I have trying for hours to understand what is going on with this SQL query.

Objective of the query: List all events taking place 6km around a given city.

After all the comments (thanks all) I moved to the query bellow using CTE, removing one useless DISTINCT and using JOINs

**BEFORE**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT c.id AS cours_id,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cl.type) AS type_loc,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cl.home,'-',cl.e)) AS home_loc,
                  MIN(ROUND(pld.distance)) AS distance,
                  pld.loc2_id AS distance_loc,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cl.home,'-',cl.e,'-',ROUND(pld.distance),'-',pld.loc2_id)) AS all_loc
 FROM cours2 c,
      cours_locations cl,
      locations_locations ll,
      (SELECT dest.id AS loc2_id, 1000 * 6371.03 * 2 * 
       ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((orig.latitude - ABS(dest.latitude)) * 
       PI()/180 / 2),2) + COS(orig.latitude * 
       PI()/180 ) * COS(ABS(dest.latitude) * 
       PI()/180) * POWER(SIN((orig.longitude - dest.longitude) * 
       PI()/180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance 
       FROM locations orig, locations dest 
       WHERE orig.id = 14861 
       AND (dest.type='V' OR dest.type='A') 
       AND dest.latitude BETWEEN orig.latitude - (6000 / 1000 / 111.045) AND orig.latitude + (6000 / 1000 / 111.045) 
       AND dest.longitude BETWEEN orig.longitude - (6000 / 1000 / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(orig.latitude)))) 
       AND orig.longitude + (6000 / 1000 / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(orig.latitude)))) 
       HAVING distance <= (6000 + 1000)) pld
 WHERE
     c.active_today = '1' AND
     c.id = cl.cours_id AND
     cl.domain = '4' AND
     c.subject_id = 404 AND
     cl.location_id = ll.rel_loc_id AND
     ll.location_id = pld.loc2_id
 GROUP BY c.id;
```

**AFTER**

```
WITH location_distances (loc_id, distance) AS (
    SELECT dest.id AS loc_id,
           1000 * 6371.03 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((orig.latitude - ABS(dest.latitude)) * PI()/180 / 2),2) + COS(orig.latitude * PI()/180 ) * COS(ABS(dest.latitude) * PI()/180) * POWER(SIN((orig.longitude - dest.longitude) * PI()/180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance
        FROM locations orig,
             locations dest
        WHERE orig.id = 14861
          AND (dest.type='V' OR dest.type='A')
          AND dest.latitude BETWEEN orig.latitude - (6000 / 1000 / 111.045) AND orig.latitude + (6000 / 1000 / 111.045)
          AND dest.longitude BETWEEN orig.longitude - (6000 / 1000 / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(orig.latitude)))) AND orig.longitude + (6000 / 1000 / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(orig.latitude))))
        HAVING distance < 7000
)
SELECT c.id AS cours_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cl.type) AS type_loc,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cl.home,'-',cl.e)) AS home_loc,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cl.home,'-',cl.e,'-',ROUND(pld.distance),'-',pld.loc_id)) AS all_loc
    FROM cours2 c
             JOIN cours_locations cl ON cl.domain = '4' AND c.id = cl.cours_id
             JOIN locations_locations ll ON cl.location_id = ll.location_id AND ll.up_propagation = 0
             JOIN location_distances pld ON ll.rel_loc_id = pld.loc_id
    WHERE c.active_today = '1'
      AND c.subject_id = 404
    GROUP BY c.id;
```

The exec time has not changed (it has even slightly increased): about 15 seconds.

The CTE part by itself runs in 290ms and returns 4 rows. This part is about finding the cities which are 6km distant from the city id 14681.

Yet, strangely:

- if I remove the HAVING clause from the CTE, it still runs in 290ms with 4 rows but this time the global query takes 60 seconds instead of 15.
- if I add a LIMIT 5 to the CTE, the global query falls to 300ms instead of 15 seconds.
- if I add a LIMIT 15 (while the number of rows is 4), it falls to 60 seconds.
  These observations can be reproduced with or without CTE, with or without JOINs.

The DB server version is 10.3.27-MariaDB

Table sizes :
cours2 c (list of events) : 15K
cours_locations cl (areas in which events take place) : 45K
locations_locations ll (hierarchy of areas - moving from a region to a city) : 310K
location_distances pld (computed cities 6km around the input city) : 5

Here is the EXPLAIN result :

```
|id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra|
|--|--------------|--------------|--------------|-------------|----------------|--------|------------|---------|---------|
|1|PRIMARY|c|ref|ID,cours2_active_today_id,cours2_active_today_domain_display_home_update_id,cours2_active_today_subject_id_id,cours2_active_today_subject_id_domain_lang_id,cours2_active_today_subject_id_lang_publish_end_id,cours2_active_today_lang_priv_loc_MOVE_subject_id_id,cours2_active_today_lang_subject_id_id,cours2_active_today_lang_priv_loc_ADR_subject_id_id,cours2_active_today_lang_priv_loc_WEBCAM_subject_id_id,cours2_subject_id_lang_id_index|cours2_active_today_subject_id_domain_lang_id|5|const,const|179|Using where; Using index; Using filesort|
|1|PRIMARY|cl|ref|PRIMARY,domain,location_id,cours_locations_domain_home_cours_id_index|PRIMARY|27|db.c.id,const|2|Using where; Using index|
|1|PRIMARY|ll|ref|PRIMARY,rel_loc_id|rel_loc_id|4|db.cl.location_id|7|""|
|1|PRIMARY|<derived2>|ref|key0|key0|4|db.ll.location_id|10|""|
|2|DERIVED|orig|const|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|4|const|1|""|
|2|DERIVED|dest|range|locations_type_D_id,locations_type_longitude_latitude|locations_type_longitude_latitude|9||1174|Using index condition; Using where|
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a version with 2 CTE running at 300ms total. This is really helping MariaDB to find the proper JOIn optimisation...

```
WITH
    location_distances (loc_id, distance) AS (
        SELECT dest.id AS loc_id,
               ROUND(1000 * 6371.03 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((orig.latitude - ABS(dest.latitude)) * PI()/180 / 2),2) + COS(orig.latitude * PI()/180 ) * COS(ABS(dest.latitude) * PI()/180) * POWER(SIN((orig.longitude - dest.longitude) * PI()/180 / 2), 2) ))) AS distance
            FROM locations orig,
                 locations dest
            WHERE orig.id = 14861
              AND (dest.type='V' OR dest.type='A')
              AND dest.latitude BETWEEN orig.latitude - (6000 / 1000 / 111.045) AND orig.latitude + (6000 / 1000 / 111.045)
              AND dest.longitude BETWEEN orig.longitude - (6000 / 1000 / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(orig.latitude)))) AND orig.longitude + (6000 / 1000 / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(orig.latitude))))
            HAVING distance < 7000
    ),
    location_distances_hierarchy (parent_loc_id, loc_id, distance) AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT ll.location_id, ld.loc_id, ld.distance
            FROM locations_locations ll,
                 location_distances ld
            WHERE ll.rel_loc_id = ld.loc_id
    )
SELECT c.id AS cours_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cl.type,'-',cl.home,'-',cl.e,'-',ldh.distance,'-',ldh.loc_id)) AS all_loc
    FROM cours2 c
        JOIN cours_locations cl ON cl.domain = '4' AND c.id = cl.cours_id
        JOIN location_distances_hierarchy ldh ON cl.location_id = ldh.parent_loc_id
    WHERE c.active_today = '1'
      AND c.subject_id = 404
    GROUP BY c.id;
```

New EXPLAIN result :

```
|id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra|
|1|PRIMARY|ss|ref|PRIMARY,subject_id|PRIMARY|4|const|1|Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort|
|1|PRIMARY|c|ref|ID,cours2_active_today_id,cours2_active_today_domain_display_home_update_id,cours2_active_today_subject_id_id,cours2_active_today_subject_id_domain_lang_id,cours2_active_today_subject_id_lang_publish_end_id,cours2_active_today_lang_priv_loc_MOVE_subject_id_id,cours2_active_today_lang_subject_id_id,cours2_active_today_lang_priv_loc_ADR_subject_id_id,cours2_active_today_lang_priv_loc_WEBCAM_subject_id_id,cours2_subject_id_lang_id_index|cours2_active_today_subject_id_domain_lang_id|5|const,trouver-un-cours.ss.rel_subject_id|30|Using where; Using index|
|1|PRIMARY|caf|eq_ref|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|26|trouver-un-cours.c.id|1|""|
|1|PRIMARY|cl|ref|PRIMARY,domain,location_id,cours_locations_domain_home_cours_id_index|PRIMARY|27|trouver-un-cours.c.id,const|2|Using where; Using index|
|1|PRIMARY|<derived3>|ref|key0|key0|4|trouver-un-cours.cl.location_id|10|Using where|
|3|DERIVED|<derived2>|ALL|||||1174|Using temporary|
|3|DERIVED|ll|ref|rel_loc_id|rel_loc_id|4|ld.loc_id|7|""|
|2|DERIVED|orig|const|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|4|const|1|""|
|2|DERIVED|dest|range|locations_type_D_id,locations_type_longitude_latitude|locations_type_longitude_latitude|9||1174|Using index condition; Using where|
```

Comment: What makes you think "it could run in 300mS"? What does the `EXPLAIN` look like? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain/

Comment: Do you _really_ need distinct? Can you remove the distinct by doing more correct joins? Distinct can cause performance issues.

Comment: How big are the tables and what fields are indexed?

Comment: The EXPLAIN result has been added. I think it can run much faster since the derived table by itself runs in 200ms and when replaced by another table of same cardinality, the global query runs in 300ms.

Comment: Removing the DISTINCTs keep the exec time unchanged.

Comment: The indexed fields are showed in the EXPLAIN. The size of the tables are : cours (15K), cours_locations (45K), locations_locations (310K), derived pld (5)

Comment: As you are using aggregate functions in the outer select, the `DISTINCT` is, or should be, redundant. You are missing at least `pld.loc2_id` in your `GROUP BY`. I have to say this code looks horrible. I'd be inclined to turn the big subquery into a CTE, and to use some proper `JOIN`s rather than using commas in the `FROM` and relying on the `WHERE` clause. Not sure any of this will make a performance difference, but seems like good practice and will make it easier for us to interpret your code.

Comment: Thanks, I have made some changes and updated the question. At this stage unfortunately no improvements.

Comment: I was wondering if it could be possible that MariaDB is not running the JOIN in the most optimal order (the most restrictive one) and ends with billion of rows depending on the way the derived query is structured. To validate that hypothesis, I created a second CTE which is now giving a good result.

Comment: The EXPLAIN should tell you what order it has decided to run everything in. Generally a query plan is not going to do a cross join (the only way you would end up with billions of rows based off source tables with 310K rows). The biggest row count in your EXPLAIN is 1,174. It would be interesting to compare EXPLAIN's between the two

Comment: So far the new query is running just fine. It is a matter of understanding intellectually what was wrong before. The new EXPLAIN has been added. Thanks again for the analysis.